# Aptana Studio 3 won't launch. It's only seeing java 1.6 not 1.8

Tags: java, jvm, aptana

I've installed Aptana studio 3 but it won't launch.  It says my java 1.6 isn't up to date.  I actually have 1.8 installed (the correct version), but Aptana is only seeing 1.6?

Comment: Please tell us whether you are running Windows or Linux.  Have you configured your Java environment variables yet?

Comment: Osx High Sierra